# C# DateTime serialization problems?

Tags: c#

I stumbled upon some strange behavior. I have sender and receiver services on two different machines in same local network and want pass this object over **UdpClient**:

```
public class SendMe
{
    public DateTime ExpirationDateUtc { get; set;}
}
```

I create it like this:

```
return new SendMe { ExpirationDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow };
```

and then I just use serialization through **BinaryFormatter**:

```
new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, obj);
return stream.ToArray();
```

and deserialization at receiving end:

```
return (SendMe)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(stream);
```

What happens next is I get difference in time (isn't UtcNow should give global timestamp?) **exactly by 7 seconds**.

What can cause such difference in time for two local network computers? I have Win7 and Win10 on them with different localization.

Comment: Have you checked if both PCs have a synchronised clock? ie. synchronise to internet time

Comment: What exactly is the difference?

Comment: Obvious questions: does that minimal example actually reproduces the problem? Secondly,  how you _calculate_ that 7 seconds offset? Do you log to console on system A reading "10:00:00" and in system B you read "10:00:07"? I strongly think it's something outside that code or wrong "measure". If you just compare with local clocks then...well...yku know...

Comment: Yes, I log it to console in real time on both systems.

Comment: Do you log received value or local clock? Please include that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computers probably have a 7 second time difference.  At my previous job, every computer had a different time displayed, with some differences as little as 5 seconds and, some as much at 9 minutes.  They were, obviously, all on the same local network.  Like **Shameen** said, check to make sure they're synchronized.

Comment: Yes, problem were exactly in synchronization! I synchronized both of machines and the problem got away!

Comment: Good stuff @eocron06.